# Getting a message from MQTT broker stops page from working

Tags: php, mqtt

I'm using a simple MQTT client in PHP - https://github.com/sskaje/mqtt - and want to retrieve exactly one message (which is retained - always there) from broker, and then display it on a page. Everything works good, but I cannot get it to display the whole page. It displays "Test Text 1", then debugging code, then my message, and stops there, not showing "Test Text 2" nor "Test Text 3". If anyone would help me, I would be incredibly grateful, as I have no idea at all, what does not work, and have spent a lot of time working on it. Thanks!

```
Test Text 1
<?php

require('spMQTT.class.php');

$mqtt = new spMQTT('tcp://127.0.0.1:1883/');

spMQTTDebug::Enable();
$mqtt->setKeepalive(5);
$connected = $mqtt->connect();
if (!$connected) {
    die("Not connected\n");
}


$topics['#'] = 0;

$mqtt->subscribe($topics);
$mqtt->loop('default_subscribe_callback');
$mqtt->unsubscribe(array_keys($topics));


printf("Test Text 2"); 

/**
 * @param spMQTT $mqtt
 * @param string $topic
 * @param string $message
 */
function default_subscribe_callback($mqtt, $topic, $message) {
    printf("Message received: Topic=%s, Message=%s\n", $topic, $message);
    break;
}
?>
Test Text 3
```

Comment: I'm not confident this will ever work, MQTT is asynchronous, there is no way to guarantee that the MQTT broker will deliver any  message during the period that the `mqtt->loop` is running for before the unsubscribe is processed.

Comment: I know MQTT is not meant to work in such a scenario, but so far it works. I just have to solve my problem with the rest of page not displaying :/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with that mqtt library, but it looks very much like the call to `loop()` is blocking, so you will have to approach the problem differently.